# How to define data type for Expand API in RAML

Tags: api, raml

I am designing an API operation and am going to use the expand standard.

Here is an example of my first API response....

```
{
    "id": "000000001",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-12-19T16:39:57-08:00",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2017-12-19T16:45:57-08:00",
    "holdingDetails": {
        "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
        "instrument": "/api/v1//instruments/123456789"
    }
}
```

Here is an example of my second API response....

```
{
    "id": "000000001",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-12-19T16:39:57-08:00",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2017-12-19T16:45:57-08:00",
    "holdingDetails": {
        "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
        "instrument": {
          "instrumentId":"123456789",
          "nickName":"My NickName",
          "type": "BLAH"    
        }
    }
}
```

In my raml I would like to define a type for this i'm not sure what is would look like...

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
properties:
  id?:
    type: string
  createdDateTime?:
    type: datetime
  lastUpdatedDateTime?:
    type: datetime

What goes next? i.e. How do I say it can be either listed below   

instrument?:
  type: string
  description: A link to the instrument

  instrument?:
    type: !include instrument.raml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *[union](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#union-type)*
e.g.:

```
instrument?:
  type: string | InstrumentType
```

and of course also define InstrumentType, for example with something like this:

```
InstrumentType:
   properties:
     instrumentId:
     nickName:
     type:
```